# Jquery for mobile devices

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, fixed

I have searched online for over a week to find a solution to this without success.

I can make a div become fixed using the following jquery

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 400) {
        $("#menu-bar").addClass("fixed");
    }
    else {
        $("#menu-bar").removeClass("fixed");
    }
});
```

However, on mobile devices it is delayed and won't show until I stop scrolling.

I have tried dozens of variations found online. I've read a lot of comments saying that it can't be done but http://www.theme.co do it very well. I've even tried using their code but no joy!

Comment: Please create a jsFiddle or a SO snippet showing the issue and be sure to show us the CSS rule for `fixed`

Comment: try to add jquery mobile https://jquerymobile.com/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0b6mzrnr/2/

Comment: This question is not clear. What are you trying to accomplish? A menu bar? Have you looked at: https://api.jquerymobile.com/toolbar/ ?

Comment: Ok, There's a div that is say 100px from the head of the browser. When the user scrolls down and the div hits the top of the browser it should become fixed. This works fine on desktops computers but on mobile devices it doesn't become fixed until the user stops scrolling and then it takes a while. It looks glitchy and awkward.